# Concrete5 Site - Multiple Collaborators/Admins

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7, concrete, concrete5-8.x

My friend and I are working on a Concrete5 website. At the moment, the site is in my friend's localhost. Is there a way that I can connect to his site and edit (develop) it?
We do not have a domain now, so we cannot publish the site anywhere.

Comment: Make a remote repository, pull/push from/to there.

Comment: We do not have a domain purchased yet and that is the main reason we are trying to figure out a solution here.